# [google-assistant-sdk]- broadcasting problem

Tags: broadcast, google-assistant-sdk

I want to broadcast by google assistant sdk (https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python).
I send command ("broadcast dinner is ready" )to SDK and I receive response as "alright broadcasting now".
But my google home mini is not broadcasted anything.
6-7 month ago, broadcast feature was working fine.
Why broadcast feature is not working now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the device running the SDK is on the same local network as your Google Home devices you're broadcasting too.

Also, you need to disable IPv6 locally for some reason.